# Scroll only WKInterfaceTable - WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacecontroller

I have this situation:

one `WKInterfaceController` within an `WKInterfaceTable` and a `Group` within one label.
I want to do this:

insert the group and below it the table but only table has to scroll and the group must be in the top of the `WKInterfaceController`, but I tried to implement this solution but I get that scroll the whole `WKInterfaceController` content (group too).

[image]

Is it possibile implement this solution in Apple Watch?
In iOS its very simple to do this, but using WatchKit I can't to do.

Comment: nobody can help me?

Comment: I wanted to do this too, but can't find a solution.